# Can someone possibly explain how the bit shifting is taking place in the below program?

Tags: java

public class Main {

```
      public static void main(String[] args){
          byte x = -7;
          System.out.println(x>>2);
          System.out.println(x>>>2);
      }
```

}

Comment: This is just fundamental language knowledge. GIve http://www.erpgreat.com/java/java-bitwise-shift-operators.htm a look, then ask more if you have questions.

Answer (score 1):

The '>>' operator shifts right preserving sign, while the '>>>' operator shifts right without preserving sign (shifts in zeros). Bit shifting can not be performed on a byte in Java so it is first promoted to an int.

So -7 (promoted to an int) in binary is this:

```
11111111111111111111111111111001
```

Shifting right by two with the '>>' operator gives us:

```
11111111111111111111111111111110
```

which is -2 in decimal. Now using the '>>>' operator instead we get:

```
00111111111111111111111111111110
```

which is 1,073,741,822 in decimal.

Comment: The compiler says otherwise. The '>>>' is giving me 1073741822 instead of 62 because byte is upgraded to int during bit shift operations.

Comment: @Birendra oops you are correct. I am getting my Java and C mixed up. I am correct on what the operators do, but in Java you cannot bit shift on a byte. The number will first be promoted to an int. the signed shift should still give you -2. I will update the answer.

Answer (score 1):

`>>` and `>>>` are the [signed and unsigned right shift operators](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op3.html). Like all other numeric operators, they will perform the operation on `int` or `long` values, so the `byte` is implicitly converted to `int` before the shift.

The binary/decimal values you see are:

```java
11111001                         // byte x = -7
11111111111111111111111111111001 // x as an int
11111111111111111111111111111110 // x >> 2
00111111111111111111111111111110 // x >>> 2
-2         // 11111111111111111111111111111110 in decimal
1073741822 //   111111111111111111111111111110 in decimal
```